# degree symbol in TextView

Tags: xml, symbols, degrees

I want to know how to make a degree symbol for an angle in a Text View (android). There are a few questions similar to this, I have tried them but they don't seem to work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_counter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"

    android:text="..."

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="80dp"
    android:textColor="#FFA500" />
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

XML doesn't use C-style escapes, it uses HTML-style character entities.  Try this:

```
android:text="50&#x2103;"
```

As you mention in the comment, U+2103 isn't what you want, you want this:

```
android:text="50&#xb0;"
```

Comment: yeah that works, but i just want a degree symbol for a angle.

Comment: @JackTrowbridge, yes, sorry, when you put 2103 in your example, I thought you wanted 2103!  U+B0 is the plain degree symbol.

Comment: How did you come by this properties? I need styles for pressure and altitudes as well as temperature. can you assist?

Comment: @RoyDoron It's a bit late, but try `#x2103;` for `℃` and `&#xb0;` for `°`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
android:text= "50&#x2103;"
```

See also [Unicode in XML and other Markup Languages](http://unicode.org/reports/tr20/).

Answer (score 5):

**In Code:**

```
myTextView.setText ( "78" + (char) 0x00B0 );

                "OR"
```

**In XML:**

```
android:text="50&#x2103;"
```

Answer (score 4):

in xml - if you want just the symbol without F or C just use:

```
      "\u00B0"
```

like this:

```
      android:text="50\u00B0"
```